# how to send payload to specific user by python autobahn/twisted

Tags: websocket, twisted, autobahn

I have gone through many forums and sites but did not find any solutions that can solve my problem.

I have this server.py file :

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
WebSocketServerFactory


class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
        else:
            print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))
            print("Text message received: {0}".format(self.peer))


        # echo back message verbatim
        self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    from twisted.python import log
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://127.0.0.1:9000")
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
    # factory.setProtocolOptions(maxConnections=2)

    # note to self: if using putChild, the child must be bytes...

    reactor.listenTCP(9000, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

What I want to do is inside onMessage I want to receive the payload from a client and then send that payload to another client, I don't want to echo back the payload to the same client.

Currently I can receive the payload successfully. But what is the way to send that payload to a different client?

I have seen similar questions in many sites but none of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on the FAQ "[How do I make input on one connection result in output on another?](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother)"

Essentially, you just need a reference to the protocol for the other connection so you can call `sendMessage` on it.  That reference may take the form of an attribute on your `MyServerProtocol` or on the factory or another object.  Perhaps it will be a direct reference to another protocol instance or perhaps it will be a collection (a list, a dict, a set) for more complicated interactions.

Once you have the reference, you just call `sendMessage` with it and the message goes to that connection instead of the connection that `self` represents.